# VLOOKUP or Multi Join Columns

Tags: sql

I have two two tables something like that:

```
          TABLE 1    as tb1                              TABLE 2 as tb2

 CLMN 1      CLMN 2    CLMN 3                          CLMN 1           ID
   a           b         a                               a               1
   c           a                                         b               2
   b           c                                         c               3
```

What I want to see in the result:

```
 CLMN 1      CLMN 2      CLMN 3       ID1      ID2       ID3
   a           b           a           1        2         1
   c           a                       3        1
   b           c                       2        3
```

To sum, I want to do vlookup with this two tables.

Note: These tables are given as examples, there is much more data in the original dataset. I want to learn how can I do vlookup

Comment: @user13619579 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two joins:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t2_1.id, t2_2.id, t2_3.id
from tb1 t1 left join
     tb2 t2_1
     on t2_1.col1 = t1.col1 left join
     tb2 t2_2
     on t2_2.col1 = t1.col2 left join
     tb2 t2_3
     on t2_3.col1 = t1.col3
```

Note the use of `left join`.  Some of your columns have non-matching values (presumably `NULL`) and you still want to keep the rows.